# Is there any other word meaning "prick" with initial onsets "pr-" except prick?

Tags: word-choice, semantics, morphology

This is my edited question:

I look up in the etymological dictionay about **prick**, and find that prick is not a word derived from **Proto-indo-european etymon**.

Meanwhile, I find a lot of words meaning "**prick, stick, pierce, spear, rod, etc.**",

words starting with "***br-***"

> such as ***brad, bristle, brittle***

words starting with "***st-***"

> such as ***stick, stake, stipe***

and find ***pierce***, which contains p and r, but etymologically it is composed with ****per1*** "forward, through" + ****(s)teu-1*** "To push, stick, knock, beat".

So, I start to wonder whether there is or no words derived from PIE, which starts with "pr-" and has the similar meaning to prick, such as "**prick, stick, pierce, spear, rod,etc.**".

Comment: Can you tell us the situation that led to such a question? Why do you need such a word? How did you try to look for such a thing? Have you checked out a thesaurus already for 'prick', 'stick' or 'pierce'?

Comment: Are you looking for "prod"?

Comment: @Mitch Hi! I look up in the etymology about prick and only find that prick is not a word derived from Proto-indo-european etymon, and I start to wonder whether PIE descendants don't have any word starting with "pr-" has the similar meaning to prick

Comment: You should include that in the question body to substantiate and give some context to the question. Edit the post.

Comment: @Kris Thanks for you suggestion and this is my edited question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are quite a few.

Here's [a synopsis](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/pr.pdf) of English simplex words beginning with **PR-**, an assonance that has strong [phonosemantic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/monobib.pdf) coherence (above 70%).

It shows that there are 18 such that share a physical *One-Dimensional (Extended)* sense, including

> *prod pry prop prong prick prone pretzel*

However, far more of these words (45, over 50%), refer to the *Human (Social Role)* sense, including

> *proud prior pride prep prince prance prim*

This very genteel Human sense of *pr-* is correlated with the *Human (Gender Role)* [senses of **BR-**](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/assonances.pdf):

> Male: *bris brute brawl brag brave bruise bray brawn brandish britches*
>   Female: *breast bride bra brat bread braid brood broil broth braise broad*

which are anything but genteel.

Comment: It is not clear what 'One dimensional (Extended)' means with respect to 'Human (Social Role)'. Also, is there a pattern the differentiates male and female in your latter example?

Comment: Ah, an attachment ambiguity. What correlates with the Human (Gender Role) sense in BR- is the Human (Social Role) sense in PR-. Not the 1-D Extended sense in PR-. Assonances with several phonosemantic foci are common, but the foci are normally independent, unless there's an embodied image involved.

Comment: @Mitch, thank you for having reminded me the phonestheme question, which was my last serious question on this site. I love it too much (or, hmmm, so much). And don't forget to upvote this great answer of John, thank you again.

Comment: @JohnLawler: OK. I get now that social and gender roles are correlated (under 'pr-') but I stil have no idea what 1-D (extended could possibly mean. Pretzels don't really stick out in one dimension, or a prop.

Comment: It's all explained in [the paper](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/WomenMen&BristlyThings.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks very much!! I think these words starting with pr- must contain some phonosemantic information

Comment: You're welcome. There's [a lot more](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/#mono) if you're interested.